# Getting Size of JPanel Object from another class in java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

How can i get the Dimension (no matter if prefferedSize or Size) of a JPanel which is build in another class?

in the class where i build the GUI i instanziate a new Panel like this:

```
PlotPanel specificPlot = gui.BuildPlottingData.makeImagePlot(discDbSpecific, sections,
windowLength, 1, algoParam1, algoParam2, leadWindowSize, 0, errorAcc);
```

As you can see this panel is to behave like a normal JPanel:

```
public class PlotPanel extends JPanel {...
```

I set its preferredSize correctly (it is visualized correctly).

Calling `specificPlot.getPreferredSize()` gives 'java.awt.Dimension[width=10,height=10]' thats obviously wrong..

Btw:
Do you have any idea how to handle this Bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4915023

BoxLayout sometimes cutting off the Panel..
thats the reason why i need to have access to the Size... i tried everything so far... or do you know an alternative Layoutmanager with same resuts like vertical BoxLayout w/o need to manualy reading the Size?

Earlier post reffer to same problem..
**Edit:** I override the `getPreferredSize`-method. Problem is that i dont have access to all parameters wich influencing the Size as follows

```
package getdata;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JPanel{

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
    return new Dimension(10,20);
    
}
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setBackground(Color.white);
    Graphics2D paint = (Graphics2D) g;

    paint.drawString("test", 0, 10);
    int strWdt = paint.getFontMetrics().stringWidth("test");
}
```

}

how to read strWdt? even if instanziate in class it will have initial value.

Answer (score 2):

- no idea, without posting an [SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable](http://sscce.org/)

> Do you have any idea how to handle this Bug:
> https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4915023

answer is described in evaluation, and rest is question - [(Should I avoid the use of set[Preferred|Maximum|Minimum]Size methods in Java Swing?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

> How can i get the Dimension (no matter if prefferedSize or Size) of a
> JPanel which is build in another class?

1. JPanel (valid for all JComponents) returns own Dimension in the case that

- is visible on the screen
- after `JFrame(JDialog, etc.).pack()` is called

2. override getPreferredSize for JPanel
3. JPanel has FlowLayout implemented in API
4. BoxLayout accepting (in compare with rest of LayoutManagers) min, max and preferred size

Comment: Thank you so far and sorry for missing SSCCE.. its simply a jpanel from another class.. When i override `getPreferredSize()` i get the correct Size. The problem is that in this method i dont have access to all parameters which influence the hight of the Panel.. (setting them in the overritten ´paintComponent()`-method ...

Comment: overload those methods, create private voids, constructor